# Question on the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I have a couple questions regarding the Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem:

**Question 1:**

Regarding the standard proof of the theorem, there is usually a mention of using the nested interval property to assert the intersection of the nested intervals:

I$_1$ $\supseteq$ I$_2$ $\supseteq$ ... $\supseteq$ I$_j$ $\supseteq$ ...

But the nested interval property asserts the intersection is nonempty, which could mean the intersection has more than one point in it. Most proofs of the theorem then pick some arbitrary $x$ from the intersection of the I$_J$ intervals and construct an argument to show the subsequence converges to $x$. But it seems this argument suggests either the intersection of the I$_j$ is a singleton set or the subsequence converges to multiple points. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is hausdorff, I would conclude the intersection must be a singleton set. Is this correct in this case?

**Question 2:**

In the standard proof that leverage dividing successive intervals in half and use the fact that one of the new intervals must contain an infinite number of points, shouldn't the proof author specify we are not in the case where the sequence (x$_n$) may have an infinite number of points that repeat themselves? For then we are not guaranteed an interval would have an infinite number of points.

Thanks!

I've linked a standard treatment of the Bolzano-Weirstrass theorem below:

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~npgallup/m17_mat25/lecture_notes/lecture_12/m17_mat25_lecture_12_notes.pdf

Comment: For your second question, you're already done in this case! If $x_n=y$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then choose this as your subsequence!

Comment: right, completely agree, i just feel authors should make a note of that, for else their case 2 would break down without specifying it is a separate case with specific conditions

Comment: This doesn't break down though. Inspecting the proof more closely may reveal the fact that we never care if points are repeated or not

Comment: in the linked proof above: the author claims the bisection of the intervals would leave an infinite number of points in at least one of the two halves . However, (x_n) may end up repeating it self infinitely often so when we consider the set $S$ = {$x_n$ | n$\in$$\mathbb{N}$ } we will have potentially only a finitely number of points in the set $S$ and hence only a finitely many number of points in the interval [M,-M]

Answer (score 1):

1. Actually the author should claim that the intersection is a singleton first. It is nonempty, and it is contained in a sequence of intervals with length approach $0$. The Hausdorff property indicates that it shall be a singleton. Let this be $\{x\}$. Now show that $a_{n_k} \to x$ by definition.
2. That does not matter, since the intervals are **closed**. Even if the sequence repeat itself at, say, $x = 0$, the $I_1$ could be either $[0, M]$ or $[-M, 0]$. Either of them could work.

Special case, say $x_n = (-1)^n$, then the value set $S = \{-1,1\}$. But in the proof we pick an interval that **contains infinitely many terms**, so either $[0,M]$ or $[-M, 0]$  meet the requirement: the former contains $x_2,x_4,x_6, \dots$, and the latter contains $x_1, x_3, x_5, \dots$.

Comment: if the sequnce was 0,0,0,0,0,.... how could there be an infinite number of points in either [0,M] or [-M,0]?

Comment: @H_1317 Check the proof at your hand. Focus on **infinitely many terms**.

Comment: ah yes, you are correct. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion for your first answer is correct. For your second question, you're already done in this case! If $x_n=y$ for infinitely many $n$, then choose this as your subsequence!